# $(x_n)$ be bounded, and $A=\{ x_n\ |\ n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ If $A$ has only one accumulation point, say x, then $x_n$ is convergent to x.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I was trying to prove the following proposition;

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence, and define $$A = \{ x_n\ |\ n\in
> \mathbb{N}\}.$$ If $A$ has only one accumulation point, say $x$, then
>   $x_n$ is convergent, and it is convergent to $x$.

However, assuming that $A$ has only one accumulation point is not useful, and if I consider the contrapositive statement, it is much more thing to prove I think, so I basically stuck.

So, how can we prove this proposition ?

**Note:** Any hint also would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
After @Carlos's answer, the sequence might be Cauchy instead of just being bounded.

Comment: Is your sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ or in an arbitrary metric space?

Answer (score 1):

But, the result is not true. Consider the next sequence
\begin{equation}
x_n=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{n} & \text{if} & n \ \text{is odd}\\\\
2 & \text{if} & n \ \text{is even}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

The sequence is bounded and only have one accumulation point (0 is accumulation point) but not converges.

**EDIT:** After the edit of the question, if the sequence is Cauchy, obviously the counterexample doesn't works. Then, let $\varepsilon>0$. Because $x_0$ is the only accumulation point, then, $\left(x_0-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},x_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. But, the sequence is Cauchy, then, for the same $\varepsilon$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geq N$, $d(x_n,x_m)<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$. Then, because the set $\left(x_0-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},x_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\cap A$ is infinite (why?), we can take $x_j\in \left(x_0-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},x_0+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right)\cap A$ such that $j\geq N$, then, if $n\geq N$, we have the next inequalities: $$d(x_n,x_0)\leq d(x_n,x_j)+d(x_j,x_0)<\frac{\varepsilon}{4}+\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$$Thus, we have the desired result.

Comment: 2 is not an accumulation point. In fact, is an isolated point because $(1.5,2.5)\cap A=\{2\}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Since $( B(2, 0.5) - \{2\} ) \cap A = \emptyset$, $2$ is not an accumulation point of $A$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos.  OP should clarify if he means cluster point, accumulation point, limit point, adherance point because there is no universally accepted definition of those terms.

Comment: @onurcanbektas, see the edition of the answer using the extra hypothesis.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: The question talks about $A$ having only one accumulation point. And $A$ is a set, not a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

1)$P$ is an accumulation point of a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in.\mathbb{N}}$ if there is a subsequence converging to $P.$

Let $(x_n)$ be bounded and consider the set

$A= ${$x_n |  n \in \mathbb{N}$}. Let $A$ have only one accumulation point $P$.

Since $P$ is accumulation point of A:

In every $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $P$ there is an $x_n \not= P$.

$\rightarrow$

A subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to $P.$

However, $(x_n)$ need not converge.

Example by CJimenez.

1) A subsequence converges to the accumulation point $P(0)$ of the set $A$, another subsequence converges to the isolated point $P'(2)$ of  $A.$

Note:

1) Point $0$ and point $2$, are both accumulation points of the sequence $(x_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}.$

2) Point $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$ , point $2$ is an isolated point of $A$.